# Как создать raid 1, или получить информацию с дисков?

Tags: linux, debian, raid

Поднял сервер на debian8, систему установил на отдельный диск. Два диска WD взял с synology. Там они находились в raid1. Хотелось бы не стирая с дисков информации снова включить диски в raid1. Подскажите как это сделать.
если сделать это невозможно, то хотя бы извлечь информацию с дисков.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 sdc5[0]
      2925531648 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>



fdisk -l /dev/sdc /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4ECEA6BB-8B09-43FC-9C8A-21FDF196DE0A

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      256    4980735    4980480  2.4G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc2  4980736    9175039    4194304    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc5  9453280 5860519007 5851065728  2.7T Linux RAID

Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C70DB86E-61C2-467C-87A5-98D4A0D372E0

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      256    4980735    4980480  2.4G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  4980736    9175039    4194304    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb5  9453280 5860519007 5851065728  2.7T Linux RAID
```

Comment: Вам raid0 нужен ради размера или для скорости?

Comment: sdb у вас почему то не в рейде. я сомневаюсь что 1 можно превратить в 0 без потери информации. на данный момент я вижу что sdc5 один диск из зеркала. смонтируйте /dev/md2 куда нибудь и спокойно спишите  с него инфу

Comment: ошибся. мне необходимо собрать в raid1 (зеркалирование). Хотел примонтировать md2 и скопировать, но не получается:       /dev/md2 /mnt/sdc ext3 user,auto,rw 0 0
bash: /dev/md2: Permission denied


sudo mount /dev/md2
mount: can't find /dev/md2 in /etc/fstab


sudo mount /dev/sdb5
mount: can't find /dev/sdb5 in /etc/fstab

Comment: 1. в комментариях многострочный вывод нечитабелен. дописывайте его в вопрос. 2. приложите вывод команды `sudo fdisk -l /dev/md2`. 3. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @RomanZhuravskiy: "хотя бы извлечь информацию с дисков" - а сейчас к данным доступа разве нет? Если sdc5 примонтировать - с него данные считать не удаётся? А добавить диск обратно в программный массив можно через `mdadm -a /dev/md2 /dev/sdb5` (http://wiki.dieg.info/mdadm). Но я бы вначале с существующего диска данные скопировал бы, а потом второй туда возвращал, фиг его от чего он отвалился.

Comment: @RomanZhuravskiy А что показывает mdadm -D /dev/md2? Меня удивило, что md2 вообще собрался, В /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf есть что-то?